# Angular 5: Combination of *ngFor and ngIf with a whole array

Tags: angular5, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I have an array which i iterate with `ngFor` in the view as shown below.
I want to hide the button if all elements of `y.errortyp` are `nottested`.

How can i achieve this functionality? I tried some combinations of `ngIf`, but can not find a solution.

```
<...>
     <tr *ngFor="let x of x">
          <td> x.name</td>
          <td *ngFor="let y of x.results">
            <div *ngIf="y.errortyp == 'Error1'" class="red"></div>
            <div *ngIf="y.errortyp == 'nottested'" class="grey"></div>
          </td>
          <td>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" aria-label="Left Align"
                (click)="download(x)">
          Download
             </button>
         </td>
<...>
```

Comment: You want to hide the button, if all the elements are 'nottested' ?.

Comment: yes, i want that

Comment: Hi,please tel me that x.results is an array of object?

Comment: Hello A. Sakkeer, 
yes, x.results is an array of objects

Comment: <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" aria-label="Left Align" (click)="download(x)" *ngIf="x.results[0].errortype == 'nottested'"> Download </button>

Comment: Try this, ans let me know if there is any issue

Comment: This shows the button if the first element of the array has the errortyp nottested.

I need this the other way around and for all elements of x.results

Comment: Can you put your code in online IDE ? jsFiddle or Plunkr , etc

Comment: Unfortunately I can not post the code directly. How would you change the code?

It musst be something like 

*ngIf="x.results[0].errortype !== 'nottested' && x.results[1].errortype !== 'nottested"

But this must consider that i do not have information about how large this array may be. so it must also work if there are more dann two elements in the array (following this code snippet)

Comment: There is only onle element is displayed per for loop

Comment: yes of course thats why i use the nested ng for loops. 

I have not adopted your suggestion. Pleasy see the second ngfor loop which uses y. But the example should be the same.

E.g. *ngIf="y[0].errortype !== 'nottested' && y[1].errortype !== 'nottested"

Comment: @A.Sakkeer, do you have any idea?

Comment: Yeah. You have to build some logic in your TS file. Before that declare a public variable. Then put ngIf for your button tag. Set the variable as a Boolean. Set the variable value False In your ngOninit Function. Then change the value with your logic.

Comment: If i have the code, I can build the logic for you. That's why i asked to put your code in some IDE.